# Web Service 'System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Style'

Tags: windows-phone-8

For an Windows Phone 8 Application, I need to connect to a Web Service.
But when I use the Visual tool to add the service reference,
it adds a file "Reference.cs" with an error :

'System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Style'

Answer (score 1):

listen i had the same problem, so i added another attribute     [System.ServiceModel.DataContractFormat(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)]

any ways the service gave an error that i can't have both attributes

[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
[System.ServiceModel.DataContractFormat(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)]
 so when i removed the XmlSerializerFormatAttribute and just left datacontractformate it returned the desired object (response )but with all values = null
when i removed the DataContractFormat it returned null not even an empty object
so i had to call this service form my code using httpclient.postasync and passing the soap xml to it, if u need more details let me know
good luck :)